# Mixing subjunctive and indicative, "if you tripped every time someone mentions"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, subjunctive-mood

> If you tripped every time someone mentions your name, you would have
>   been dead by now.

My question is about the subordinate clause of the above sentence, "If you tripped everytime someone mentions your name...". Is the mixture of the subjunctive *tripped* and the indicative *mentions* correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

> "*If you tripped **every time** someone **mentioned** your name, you **would be dead** by now*"

or

> "*If you had tripped every time someone **mentioned** your name, you **would have been dead for** ten years by now*". Subjunctive requires the past or past perfect.

The tenses must follow the proper sequence of tenses. One cannot mix "if you tripped" and "mentions your name" and "would have been dead by now" (this would have to be "**would have died** by now" to match "**tripped**" and "**mentioned**").

The sequence of tenses is difficult.

> "*If you **trip** every time someone **mentions** your name, you **will die** soon*"

is a present conditional.

Comment: *"If you **were to trip** every time..."*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, that's the standard subjunctive form. I don't see why this ambiguous past tense form can't be used as a subjunctive as long as we understand that it's a hypothetical & not talking about something that happened in the past. *_If I was rich, I would have bought a Rolls_ is wrong; should be _If I had been rich, I would have bought a Rolls_ and _If I were rich, I would buy a Rolls_. _If I was rich, I don't remember it_ is okay, though.

Comment: "If you tripped every time someone mentioned your name, you should be dead by now" and "If you tripped every time someone mentioned your name, you were definitely a klutz" are past conditionals. In the 1st, the condition has been met, but the consequence hasn't occurred.

Comment: @BillFranke: In your example _"If you had tripped every time someone mentioned your name, you would have been dead for ten years by now"_, would it be the same if I put _had_ in _". . . every time someone **had** mentioned your name . . ."_?

Comment: @Sherlock: My feeling about this is that it doesn't work because the second _had_ is either unnecessary or ungrammatical. It seems as if the sequence of tenses is backward without the second _had_, though. I see your point: first they mention your name & then you trip. I would probably write that sentence _Had you tripped every time someone mentioned your name, you would have been dead for ten years by now_. Looking at the full S with both _had_s, I'd say it's wrong to have the 2nd _had_: _Had you tripped every time X happened,..._ feels just right to me.  Other opinions?